# masscan записывать только те хосты, которые пингуются

Tags: linux, сеть

masscan замечательная утилита, но чересчур замечательная, хотелось бы на выходе получать не все хосты, где этот порт открыт, а только те, которые имеют этот порт открытым **и** позволяют себя пинговать.

Comment: nmap? https://nmap.org/

Comment: Ну или как на nmap (по идее nmap команды можно встроить в masscan тока я ума не приложу как, маны не помогают)

Comment: --ping  https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan/blob/master/doc/masscan.8.markdown

Answer (score 1):

Только, что проверила работу тулзы

```
masscan ip/24 -p80
```

Возвращает только ip с открытым 80 портом.
На некоторых машинах может стоять запрет на пинги
но это не значит что порты закрыты. Если по дефолту
в вашей системе masscan использует другие параметры
задайте команду так

```
masscan ip/24 -p80 --open-only

masscan --nmap #посмотреть опции
```